# Angular JS Multiple ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do the following : When you click on "Add Package" its pushes to an array a package where I can specify e.g. Package one, but within that I want to push multiple items (products) "Add Item". The problem is when I create a new package it works, but the items in each package is the same so when I add more to either dynamic package the items within is the same. I assume that's because the array is the same each time, how to I track that by index?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 order-box" ng-repeat="orderpackage in orderproductspackages track by $index">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="name_{{$index}}">Package Name</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="orderpackage.orderpackagename" name="name_{{$index}}" required>                                                 
  </div>
  <div class="col-12" ng-repeat="ordercontent in orderproductscontents track by $index">                       
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="name_{{$index}}">Product</label>
      <select ng-model="ordercontent.ordercontentname" name="name_{{$index}}" ng-change="onProductChange(ordercontent.ordercontentname,$index)">
        <option ng-repeat="product in productResponse | orderBy:'productname'" value="{{product.productname}}">{{product.productname}}</option>
      </select>                                                                            
    </div>                                   
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="name_{{$index}}">Quantity</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="ordercontent.ordercontentquantity" name="name_{{$index}}" ng-keyup="onProductChange(ordercontent.ordercontentname,$index)" required>
    </div>                     
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="name_{{$index}}">Price</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="ordercontent.ordercontentprice" name="name_{{$index}}" ng-change="onPriceChange(ordercontent.ordercontentname,$index)" disabled required>                                                 
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="name_{{$index}}">Per {{ordercontent.ordercontentmeasurement}}</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="ordercontent.ordercontentpriceper" name="name_{{$index}}" disabled required>                                                 
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="name_{{$index}}">Total</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="ordercontent.ordercontenttotal" name="name_{{$index}}" required disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <label for="name_{{$index}}">Options</label>
      <a class="button critical small" ng-click="removeOrderContent($index)"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span> Remove</a> 
    </div>                    
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 m20-top p15 text-center add-api" ng-click="addOrderContent()">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Item</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 m20-top p15 text-center add-api" ng-click="addOrderPackage()">
  <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Package</a>
</div>
```

CODE SNIPPETS :

```
_this.addOrderPackage = function() {
  _this.orderproductspackages.push({ ordernumber:_this.order.ordernumber });
}

_this.addOrderContent = function() {
  _this.orderproductscontents.push({                    
    ordercontentname:'',                   
    ordercontentquantity:'1',                 
    ordercontentprice:'',
    ordercontentpriceper:'',
    ordercontenttotal:''
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, all items in your packages are the same, because you use the same content array inside packages: `ng-repeat="ordercontent in orderproductscontents"`. If I understand you right, you need this array `orderproductscontents` to be distinctive in each package. To do this store this array in package object, like this:

```
_this.addOrderPackage = function() {
  _this.orderproductspackages.push({ 
    ordernumber: _this.order.ordernumber,
    contents: []
  });
}
```

and then just `ng-repeat="ordercontent in orderpackage. contents"`